# TYPO 10.4.9 Link building issue

Tags: parsing, hyperlink, issue-tracking, building, typo3-10.x

I have two folders (Stage and Live) on a web server. The live system is a copy of the stage system.
The core (TYPO3 10.4.9) outside of the two folders is accessed via a symlink.
The stage system is provided with PW protection, otherwise the htaccess is identical.

If you call up the front end of the live system in the morning, the links are not generated on some pages. The link text or the images are showen.
The phenomenon does not occur on all pages. It affects both the html content element and the "Images only" content element.

In the html content element, the links are written with a-tag and t3://page?uid=ID.

If you manually empty the cache via the backend and open the page again in the frontend (Ctrl + f5), all links are generated.

I have already rewritten the links in the html content element from  to a-tag, compared the rights to the folders, and deactivated the ke_search scheduler task.

I'm slowly getting stuck and hope for some information from the community.
Can anyone give me a hint?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the typoscript setup. The linkVars need an language ID.

wrong:

```
config.linkVars = L
```

corrected:

```
config.linkVars = L(0,1)
```

closed.